# Basic console input and output

Tags: java, console

I'm looking for a way to basically give back to the user some console output that looks identical to what they type and then prompt again for more input. The problem is I have a method that modifies each String discovered that does not consist of white space.

At the end of each sentence given by the user, I am trying to figure out a way to get a newline to occur and then for the prompt to output to the console again saying "Please type in a sentence: ". Here is what I have so far...

```
System.out.print("Please type in a sentence: ");

    while(in.hasNext()) {
        strInput = in.next();

        System.out.print(scramble(strInput) + " ");


        if(strInput.equals("q")) {
            System.out.println("Exiting program... ");
            break;
        }

    }
```

Here is what is displaying as console output:

```
Please type in a sentence: Hello this is a test
Hello tihs is a tset
```

And the cursor stops on the same line as "tset" in the above example.

What I *want* to happen is:

```
Please type in a sentence: Hello this is a test
Hello tihs is a tset
Please type in a sentence:
```

With the cursor appearing on the same line as and directly after "sentence:"

Hopefully that helps clear up my question.

Comment: can't you just move your `please type` output INSIDE your loop, then?

Comment: Be even more specific. Specify exactly what the user should input and what output the program should give in response.

Comment: @nhouser9 Tried to be more specific. I'm not sure how to format my console output in the question so its clearly identified.

Comment: @ClownInTheMoon thanks for the edit that makes it more clear. see my answer, and if it helps please upvote and accept =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I didn't test it but it should do what you want. Comments in the code explain each line I added:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Please type in a sentence: ");
    String input = in.nextLine(); //get the input

    if (input.equals("quit")) {
        System.out.println("Exiting program... ");
        break;
    }

    String[] inputLineWords = input.split(" "); //split the string into an array of words
    for (String word : inputLineWords) {        //for each word
        System.out.print(scramble(word) + " "); //print the scramble followed by a space
    }
    System.out.println(); //after printing the whole line, go to a new line
}
```

Comment: If you need to scramble each word separately (instead of the sentence as a whole), then this is the way to go.

Comment: This worked well. Ended up using an ArrayList for a few different reasons but overall the program is working well now!

Comment: @ClownInTheMoon Happy to hear it =]

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Please type in a sentence: ");

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        strInput = in.next();

        if (strInput.equals("q")) {
            System.out.println("Exiting program... ");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(scramble(strInput) + " ");
    }
    break;
}
```

The changes are:

1. You should be printing `"Please type in a sentence: "` inside a loop to have it print again.
2. I think you want to check if the `strInput` is "q" and exit BEFORE printing it, i.e. no need to print the "q", or is there?
3. Use `println` to print the scrambled `strInput` so that the next `"Please type in a sentence: "` appears in the next line, and the cursor appears on the same line as `" ... sentence: "` because **that** is output by `System.out.print` (no `ln`)

Comment: This will print each word of the sentence on a new line. Not what OP wants.